# Select contact delegate method not calling

Tags: ios, swift

In my app i want to use `ContactsUI` framework for auto fill fields. I created button and want to get contact data when user select one:

```
class MyController: UIViewController,CNContactPickerDelegate {
     var contactStore = CNContactStore()
     @IBAction func selectContact(_ sender: Any) {
        self.requestForContactAccess { (accessGranted) -> Void in
            if accessGranted {
                let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

                contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "birthday != nil")

                contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

                self.present(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                contactPickerViewController.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey]

            }
        }

    }
}
```

And create method:

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
        print(contact)
    }
```

But contact didn't print and controller with contacts not close after select. What do i do wrong ?

Comment: this may help ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245760/contactpickerdidcancel-of-cncontactpickerdelegate-never-called

Comment: If you are using Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091 ? The Swift 3 signature of the method is `optional func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)`, you are using an old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Larme

If you are using Swift 3: stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/… ? The Swift 3 signature of the method is optional `func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)`, you are using an old one.